# Angular application is not loading my component path when manually navigated to in the browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, ng-modules

My application starts on a `login` page which has a button to a `create-account` page.

If I am on the `create-account` page and I refresh my browser, it goes back to the `login` page.

Why is that? I tried reading through the documentation to find a solution, but it wasn't entirely clear. I can see from the browser that if I manually navigate to `http://localhost/create-account`, it returns a 301 and goes back to the `login` page. What must be done to the route to fix this in order to allow `create-account` to be hit?

Here is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateAccountComponent } from './create-account/create-account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { PasswordResetComponent } from './password-reset/password-reset.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "create-account", component: CreateAccountComponent },
  { path: "password-reset", component: PasswordResetComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, it was because my `app.component.ts` had this in it, and it gets called for every route when the application is initialized (first browsed to):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

I have refactored this to:

```
ngOnInit() { }
```

I have also added a wildcard route resolver to the `LoginComponent` instead, so that URL routes that have no mapping will go to the `login` page, if you look at the last element added in the `Routes` here:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "create-account", component: CreateAccountComponent },
  { path: "password-reset", component: PasswordResetComponent },
  { path: "**", component: LoginComponent }
];
```